# Laravel passing user id to view/controller

Tags: php, laravel

I am fairly new to laravel and I have implemented a system in my project so that user can send "dm's" to eachother. But now in the create view there are checkboxes where you can check the users you want to send a dm to. I get the users like this in my create function in my controller:

```
$users = User::where('id', '!=', Auth::id())->get();
```

My goal is that users can click on other users names in other views and select an option with "send dm" or something. But I have no Idea how I can pass that id to my create function in my controller. Should I make the checkboxes hidden and select the id that is passed? Or what should my gameplan be here?

This is my create function in my controller

```
public function create($userid)
    {
        $users = User::where('id', '=', $userid);
        return view('messenger.create', compact('users'));
    }
```

These are my routes:

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'messages'], function () {
    Route::get('/', ['as' => 'messages', 'uses' => 'MessagesController@index']);
    Route::get('create/{userid}', ['as' => 'messages.create', 'uses' => 'MessagesController@create']);
    Route::post('/', ['as' => 'messages.store', 'uses' => 'MessagesController@store']);
    Route::get('{id}', ['as' => 'messages.show', 'uses' => 'MessagesController@show']);
    Route::put('{id}', ['as' => 'messages.update', 'uses' => 'MessagesController@update']);
});
```

The problem is I don't know how to fill up that $userid in my create function.
But I am not sure this is the correct way to do it, I think I might be on a completely wrong path here

Could realy use all the help

Thanks in advance!

Comment: when user click on "other users names" you need custom link using a route, and pass the variable $id to your controller, for example:  <a href="{{ route('controller-function", $id_user) }} " >some user<a/>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use links and send a single user a dm here is an approach. You need a view for the dm and view with the user.
Here is the user:

```
<a href"{{ route('createMessage', ['user_id' => $user->id]) }}">Send message to: {{ $user->name }}</a>
```

You send user_id as route parameter that holds the id of the user that you want to send a message to ($user->id).
Here is the route:

```
Route::get('/message/create/{user_id}', [
     'uses' => 'UsersController@create',
     'as' => 'createMessage'
]);
```

You get the route parameter user_id in your create methond in your controller like so:

```
public function create($user_id)
{
   $user = User::find($user_id);

   return view('messenger.create', ['user' -> $user]);
}
```

Comment: There must be a way to just send the name or id to my create view and then I can check the checkbox with the same id or name

Comment: without creating new routes and functions and whatsoever? Or am I mistaken?

Comment: Well do you select one user or can you select multiple users?

Comment: At this moment you can select multiple but the goal is just to be able to select one when you create a new dm but when you click on the "send dm" link I want that user selected already and the other checkboxes maybe hidden or something

Comment: I am sorry but why do you do a for each over all the users? An example of my goal. The user goes to the profile of an other user. There's a link with "send dm" he clicks on it he goes to the create view with the checkbox of the user he clicked is checked. An maybe the other checkboxes are hidden, is this possible ?

Comment: Okay it works, but there is one problem I can just change the user id in the  url and this way I can send a dm to someone else. Is there a way to make this more secure?

Comment: Well that isn't a security issue. If you change it so what? You send it to someone else. No security breach.

Comment: Well I have the same issue when you're viewing your dm's you can just change the id of the thread in the url for example /messages/3 -> you can change it to /messages/4 and read that thread :p maybe you know a way to make it secure I used this package btw https://github.com/cmgmyr/laravel-messenger

Comment: Imagine your account in the apps database has an user id of 5. In There are 3 messages in the database with user id 5. When you get the current authenticated user messages (user with id of 5) you get all messages that have the same as id as Auth::user()->id. In the route you get the message id not the user id. /messages/{message_id}. That way you cannot get a message that isn't meant for you.

Comment: I'm sorry but I dont understand :p So you suggest I should only query the threads of the logged in user?

Comment: Yeah the logged in user should get only the messages that have the same user id. If lets say we get the messages with the route /messages/{message_id} and the message with id 1 belongs to the currently logged in user and the message with id 2 belongs to another user and you try to go to /messages/2 you should check if the message->user_id == Auth::user()->id and if it doesn't you just redirect them somewhere with the redirect function possibly with an error message. Was this more clear and helpful?

Comment: I made a new question on how to query the right threads check it out if you want, my friend. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37555297/laravel-eloquent-query-right-data

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

Your routes :

```
Route::get('create/{userid}', ['as' => 'messages.create', 'uses' => 'MessagesController@createForm']); // to load the form
Route::post('create/{userid}', ['as' => 'messages.create', 'uses' => 'MessagesController@create']); // to create the DM
```

To load the form with the user information :

```
public function createForm($userid)
{
    $user = User::find($userid);
    return view('messenger.create', array("user" => $user));
}
```

You can passe the ID on the URL in the action attribute for example :

```
<form action="create/{{ $user->id }}" method="POST">
```

The method to create the DM:

```
 public function create($userid)
 {
     $user = User::find($userid);
     //create the DM
 }
```

---

**There is another solution, you can pass on with a hidden input**

Comment: but I don't want to use a form to pass the id just a link is this possible?

Comment: You can create another route, and a link like this :

<a href="send_dm/{{ $user->id }}>{{ $user->name }}</a>

, for the route :

Route::post('send_dm/{userid}', ['as' => 'messages.create', 'uses' => 'MessagesController@send_dm']);

Comment: I dont understand really, Why do I need to make a new function send_dm when I already have my create function?

Comment: Can't I just somehow pass the id to that view and check the checkbox with the same id?