# Laravel eloquent query right data

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

I am fairly new to laravel and eloquent.

I have 2 tables `threads` and `messages` you can see the structure in the links below:

threads

[image: threads]

messages

[image: messages]

Now my goals is to query only the threads from table threads that have the same user_id in the messages table as the logged in user .

Is there a way to do this via eloquent or do I have to write a query for this?

I currently get all the threads like this:

```
$thread = Thread::findOrFail($id);
```

But this gives security issues since you can go to any thread if you change the id in my route.

## EDIT

My current show function:

```
public function show($id)
    {
        $currentUserId = Auth::user()->id;
        $threads = Thread::forUser($currentUserId)->latest('updated_at')->get();
        
        try {
            $thread = Thread::findOrFail($id);
        } catch (ModelNotFoundException $e) {
            Session::flash('error_message', 'Oops, not found.');
            return redirect('messages');
        }

        
        if(array_has($threads, $thread)){
            $users = User::whereNotIn('id', $thread->participantsUserIds($currentUserId))->get();
            $thread->markAsRead($currentUserId);
            return view('messenger.show', compact('thread', 'users'));
        }else{
            Session::flash('error_message', 'Oops, not found.');
            return redirect('messages');
        }
        
    }
```

I need a way to check if $thread is inside $threads.

Comment: What do you mean by thread?

Comment: In a thread you can have multiple messages. So for example I create a thread "discussion1" and in this discussion there can be multiple messages. A thread is like a dm between 2 users.

Comment: @Codearts I hope It makes sense what I am trying to say :)

Comment: Yes I am writing the answer now.

Comment: So a message has only one thread and one user right?

Comment: @Codearts Yes this is correct

Comment: i think you can fix the security issue with an if statment, like if auth::user has that thread , its ok else, not authorized

Comment: @AchrafKhouadja Yeah that was my idea too that's why I am trying to query all threads from the logged in user. Unfortunately I do not have a userid stored in the threads table but in the messages table there is one.

Comment: @Codearts Do I have to explain the situation better or do you understand? :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to use eloquent you must first define a relationship.
One message belongs to a thread and a user. Here is how to define the relationships:
Inside the Message model:

```
public function user()
{
   return $this->belongsTo('App/User'); //User model
}

public function thread()
{
  return $this->belongsTo('App/Thread'); //Thread model
}
```

To define the inverse you do the following:
Inside User model:

```
public function threads()
{
  return $this->hasMany('App/Thread');
}
```

Inside the Thread model:

```
public function messages()
{
   return $this->hasMany('App/Message');
}
```

Now you can do the following in your controller:

```
$threads = Auth::user()->threads;
```

Now you have all threads by the currently logged in user.
I am not sure if I got the question right so ask away.

Edit:
You could check like so:

```
$thread = Thread::find($id);
$isCurrentUserThread = false;
foreach(Auth::user()->threads as $currentUserThread) {
   if($currentUserThread->id == $thread->id) {
       $isCurrentUserThread = true;
      //$thread belongs to the current user
   }
}

if($isCurrentUserThread) {
    //the thread belongs to the current user
} else {
   //it doesn't belong to the current user
}
```

Comment: The thing is I don't have any models since I use this package: https://github.com/cmgmyr/laravel-messenger but I found a function that they use  `$threads = Thread::forUser($currentUserId)->latest('updated_at')->get();` like this for example. Now I was trying to check if the array that is querried with the id from the route is in the array $threads

Comment: I've updated OP with my function check it out if you want

Comment: I get this error: array_key_exists(): The first argument should be either a string or an integer

Comment: he can't use that relation since he does not have user_id in threads, @cruzito the result is not an array its a collection btw , best way is to add the foreign key and use relations.

Comment: @AchrafKhouadja so is there no way to check if the $thread array(?) is in the $threads collection? Or are they both collections?

Comment: @Cruzito Look I edited my answer. Does this help you?

Comment: @Codearts wow, it seems to be working, but how exatly does the Auth::user()->threads works? where does the ->threads come from?

Comment: Auth::user()->threads work because of the relationship between the two models: User and Thread. If you didn't write the relation I guess that the package that you are using has it somewhere inside it. Checkout the docs for the relationship it will get much clearer.
https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/eloquent-relationships

Comment: If I was helpful and solved your problem, please mark my answer as correct :)

Comment: you can convert  collection to array areayres=$collection->toarray(), and you can use if(in_array) to check if its in the array(dunno what params it need, google it), any way since you found a solution good luck (i am wondering how that works too btw)

Comment: @Codearts I am going through the models in the package and can't seem to find the function so weird :p

Comment: @cruzito if you want the thread to be shown only if it belongs to that user ( or whatever con dition you like) consider using [policies](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/authorization#creating-policies)  (i know that this is answered but just to note

Answer (score 1):

There is a way to get the current user's id by calling:

```
$logged_in_user = Auth::user()->id
```

Just make sure to include this portion somewhere on top:

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
```

Then, you could just get all Messages where the user_id equals to the logged in user...

```
$messages = App\Message::where('user_id', '=', $logged_in_user)->get();
// the get() method will get all messages, not just one
```

From there, you could extract the $messages variable and grab all the thread_ids, which then, you could use the find method on the Thread model, like the following:

```
$threads = App\Thread::find([1, 2, 3, 4, ...]);
```